# StatusCode 400 Bad Request in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have this function for returning a list of decks in my DeckController that sends a request to my GetDecks function in my DeckDataController that works as expected. However when I try adding other methods I get a status code 400 bad request.

```
    //DeckController.cs
    // GET: Deck/List
    /// <summary>
    /// Get a list of all Decks
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>returns a list of Decks</returns>
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        // api string
        string url = "DeckData/GetDecks";
        
        //http request to the url
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
        Debug.WriteLine(response);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {                    
            IEnumerable<DeckDto> Decks = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<DeckDto>>().Result;    
            return View(Decks);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Error");
        }
    }


    //DeckDataController.cs
    /// Get a list of decks in the database alongside ok code (200)
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A list of decks</returns>
    /// GET: api/DeckData/GetDecks
    [HttpGet]
    [ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<DeckDto>))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetDecks()
    {
        // get the list of decks from the database
        List<Deck> Decks = db.Decks.ToList();

        // create an empty Deck data transfer object
        List<DeckDto> DeckDtos = new List<DeckDto> { };
        Debug.WriteLine("In GetDecks");


        // for each deck create a new DeckDto and push it to the list of DeckDtos.
        foreach (var deck in Decks)
        {
            DeckDto newDeck = new DeckDto
            {
                DeckID = deck.DeckID,
                DeckTitle = deck.DeckTitle
            };

            DeckDtos.Add(newDeck);

        }

        return Ok(DeckDtos);
    }
```

For example, adding the following function to my DeckDataController breaks my server.

```
    // DeckDataController.cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Finds a deck based on the deckID
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">DeckID</param>
    /// <returns>returns a DeckDto object if found, otherwise NotFound object</returns>
    [HttpGet]
    [ResponseType(typeof(DeckDto))]
    public IHttpActionResult FindDeck(int id)
    {

        // find the deck in the database
        Deck deck = db.Decks.Find(id);

        // if deck isnt found
        if (deck == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        // create a data transfer object to send back
        DeckDto DeckDto = new DeckDto
        {
            DeckID = deck.DeckID,
            DeckTitle = deck.DeckTitle
        };
        return Ok(DeckDto);
    }
```

but if I comment out the above function everything seems to be work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use this code:

```
var deck = db.Decks.Where(i=>i.DeskID==id).FirstOrDefault();
....
```